# Oracle.DataAccess (ODAC)18.3 not found in iis(4.122.18.3)

Tags: iis-10, odac, oracleclient, system.data.oracleclient

3) but in installation there are no machine level option.
I put Oracle.DataAccess and Oracle.Web in to gac manually and add DbProviderFactories to machine.config.But I got still this error.

Is someone try this odac version with iis server

> Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess,
>   PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
       <add name="ODP.NET, Unmanaged Driver" invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Unmanaged Driver" type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.122.18.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Comment: Why are you using unmanaged driver?... You should use managed driver available in nuget... MUCH easier to configure..., no versioning conflict with other apps as well.

Answer (score 1):

I add dependdentAssembly to my web.config and copy Oracle.DataAccess.dll under bin folder,and it worked

```
 <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.121.2.0" newVersion="4.122.18.3" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Mind assemblyIdentity culture attribute! Was missing from Sandro Pereira's blog post about assembly redirects. Just for name dropping...